# Is this sentence correct? "My friend, Ted, be happy."

Tags: grammar

My friend, Ted, **is** happy.--This sentence is grammatically correct. Yet, I am wondering if the sentence below is also possible.

My friend, Ted, **be** happy.

Does this mean that the person is talking to his friend, Ted and wants him to be happy?

Answer (score 3):

OP's second example is syntactically valid, but it's not something a native speaker is likely to say. I switched from ***my friend*** to ***my son*** because it makes some points easier to explain, but the principles are the same for both.

We *sometimes* include the addressee's name when speaking to them. But unless it's specifically to catch their attention (as in *"**Ted! Come over here!**"*) we normally put it at the *end* of the utterance (as in *"**I agree with you, my son.**"*). And we wouldn't use ***my son*** in the first scenario anyway; people prick their ears up when they hear their own name, not just if they hear a "family relationship" term that *might* apply to them.

Finally, we wouldn't normally identify the *addressee* twice in the same utterance. OP's *first* example is idiomatically natural (assuming the speaker thinks whoever she's talking to doesn't know her son is called Ted, OR she has more than one son, so it's for disambiguation). But obviously if the speaker is addressing her *own* son, neither of those reasons apply.

Answer (score 2):

**My friend, Ted, is happy.** would be descriptive.

In speech, one often hears:

**Ted, my friend, be happy.**

The name of the person in apposition to my friend when addressing the friend directly.

Comment: *Ted, my friend, be happy* sounds to me like a line of dialogue in a trashy novel. I find it hard to imagine a real person saying it (unless perhaps they were very drunk and maudlin).

Comment: @FumbleFingers So what? It's idiomatic. We do use names with my friend appositively. "**John my friend, be careful**. https://www.ndt.net/forum/thread.php?msgID=54713

Comment: Perhaps we have different ideas about what "idiomatic" means. Besides which, the link you've just cited is a fairly unusual "internet forum" context, from a Canadian professor whose profile lists ***French*** as his primary language (before English and German). The usage under consideration probably occurs more often in books and movies because the writers need to remind the ***reader / viewer*** about names and relationships. In the real world we don't need to do that (except maudlin drunks who feel they need to remind whoever they've fallen into conversation with that they're "friends").

Comment: @FumbleFingers One can easily imagine, one man saying to another in a difficult circumstance in English: "John, my friend, [verb etc]" appositively. This is completely idiomatic in English regardless of what you claim.

Comment: We're just repeating ourselves, Lambie, my friend. Let's just leave it at that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You come here and claim something is like a trashy novel. It is most certainly not that. It is actually very nice and all that trying to put me down saying the guy is a French speaker. So what? Your answer fails to deal with appositive uses of names are. Even you just wrote: Lambie, my friend....